# Integrating Unity With Native IOS Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I would like to integrate our unity game with our native ios application (Want to show unity game in a view controller's view) and for doing that I've followed this tutorial:
http://www.markuszancolo.at/2014/05/integrating-unity-into-a-native-ios-app/

Now Code can be build and run on device succesfully but while the execution of below line in UnityAppController, the application crashes. Does anyone know a reason for that?

```
UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String]);
```

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: it only gives a stacktrace like in this screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eSt3_PT8YXbDVnYXpuSnA2Tmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any update on this?